# ./configure doesn't work while installing mod_gzip

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, centos, gzip

I tried to install and enable mod_gzip on apache server and downloaded mod_gzip from http://sourceforge.net/projects/mod-gzip/files/

When i try to install and type ./configure, i get `./configure: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The directory that you are currently in does not contain an executable file called configure.

---

Why are you not using [mod_deflate](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_deflate.html) which is a standard module on CentOS? That mod_gzip stuff hasn't had any love for over a decade.

---

I took a peek at the mod_gzip source, there is a simple Makefile there. It doesn't work out of the box though. I can fix the first problem easily enough but the second stumps me.

Comment: Think you mean that mod_gzip stuff hasn't had any love! :-)

Comment: Yeah I did - cheers: You could have fixed it too.